# Databricks - Dplyr on SparkDataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, databricks, gapply

I am looking to run dplyr functions on a Spark dataframe.

How do I run dplyr functions on a Spark dataframe through Databricks? No matter how I modify my code it always has the same error with a different `dplyr` function.

`HDEF_df_test` is a Spark dataframe with the following structure:

```
ds        TICKER        y
1/5/22     HDEF      23.87
1/6/22     HDEF      23.90
1/7/22     HDEF      24.20
1/10/22    HDEF      24.20
1/11/22    HDEF      24.45
1/12/22    HDEF      24.60
```

Code below

```
Sys.setenv(DOWNLOAD_STATIC_LIBV8 = 1)
remotes::install_github("jeroen/V8")
devtools::install_version("rstantools", version = "2.0.0")
install.packages('prophet')

forecast <- function(x){
    library(prophet)
    library(dplyr)
    preds <- x %>%  
        dplyr::group_by(TICKER) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(weekdays = weekdays(ds)) %>% 
        dplyr::filter(weekdays != "Saturday" & weekdays != "Sunday") %>%
        dplyr::do(predict(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), 
                   filter(make_future_dataframe(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), periods = 14), weekdays(ds) != "Saturday" & weekdays(ds) != "Sunday"))) %>%
        dplyr::select(ds,
               TICKER,
               yhat)
        preds
 }
 forecast(HDEF_df_test)
```

Error below:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "SparkDataFrame"
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10pt'> Error in UseMethod(&quot;do&quot;): no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class &quot;SparkDataFrame&quot; </code
```

The error goes away when I convert the SparkDataFrame to a data.frame like so:

```
test <- SparkR::collect(HDEF_df_test)
forecast(HDEF_df_test)
```

However, when I run the next gapply function using the data.frame, it doesn't work hence why I need to keep it as a Spark.Dataframe.

```
output_schema <- SparkR::structType(
  structField("ds", "date"),
  structField("TICKER", "string"), 
  structField("yhat", "double")
)

results <- SparkR::gapply(x = test, 
                         cols = "TICKER",
                         func = forecast,
                         schema = output_schema)

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘gapply’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
```